# Ruby interpolation issue with space

Tags: ruby

I am currently coming across an issue that it seems simple but I have not been able to debug. With the following code:

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
     "#{string} "  * a
end
repeat("hello", 3)
```

I am trying to get the following output:

`expected: "hello hello hello"` 
But instead I end up getting the following output `"hello hello hello "` if I were to take the space away I would end up with an output of `"hellohellohello"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-strip):

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
  ("#{string} "  * a).strip
end

repeat('hello',3)
#=> "hello hello hello"
```

Another way is:

```
Array.new(3) {"hello"}.join(' ')
#=> "hello hello hello"
```

Also, we can have:

```
Array.new(3,"hello").join(' ')
#=> "hello hello hello"
```

Comment: Perhaps write #2 `Array.new(3, "hello").join(' ')`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nice one, have added to my answer -thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-chop) to remove the last character:

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
  ("#{string} "  * a).chop
end
```

Or you can use [array repetition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-2A):

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
  [string] * a * ' '
end
```

You can also use a more intention revealing name than `a`, such as `repetitions`, `repeating_count`, `repeating_times`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The String#rstrip function in Ruby core can be used here:

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
     ("#{string} "  * a).rstrip
end
```

This will just remove all trailing spaces from the right side.

Another option is to use Array#join ...

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
  ([string] * 2).join(" ")
end
```

Or, equivalently:

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
  a.times.map { string }.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def repeat(string, a = 1)
   Array.new(a){string}.join(' ')
end
repeat("hello", 3)
```

`Array.new(a)` will construct an array of size `a` where each position is the string. The `join(' ')` method will join the whole array by adding a space between each string.